# Как занести данные пользователя в телеграм боте в MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql, telegram-bot

Всем добрый день. Возникла задача сделать телеграм бота на Python с базой данных MYSQL. Бот при общении с пользователем отправляет кнопку(инлайновая клавиатура), а эта кнопка является ссылкой. При нажатии на кнопку(т.е. ссылку) человека перекидывает на сайт free-kassa, где он выбирает удобный ему способ оплаты и оплачивает товар (в моём случае товар является подпиской). После чего возвращается обратно в телеграм. Но я не понимаю, как мне занести в базу данных MYSQL его id (пользователя телеграм, который ОПЛАТИЛ товар),
название продукта (который этот id купил) и время покупки. Подскажите пожалуйста, что для этого нужно, как это вообще реализовать? В интернете искал, но почему-то глухо на эту тему. Как решить эту задачу, именно чтобы добавлялись эти данные: (id, название продукта, время покупки) в базу данных MYSQL. Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Разделите вашу проблему на подзадачи. По-сути ваш вопрос - "Как отправить запрос INSERT в базу данных MySQL с помощью python". Контекст для решения этой проблемы совершенно не важен.

Comment: сложность заключается в том, откуда брать название товара и время ПОКУПКИ товара, а также id покупателя

Comment: Здрасьте, вы же знаете название товара и id покупателя. А время покупки можно получить с помощью встроенной ф-ции. Момент вставки - это момент покупки

Comment: Извините, с утра еще не въезжаю в тему, момент вставки - это как?

Comment: `INSERT INTO purchases (user_id, product_id, purchases_date) VALUES (,,NOW()), (,,NOW())...;`

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а как узнать id покупателя?

Comment: И как узнать, что пользователь действительно купил товар (подписку) на free-kassa?